# solution verification :$\int_{\gamma}Re(z)+Im(z)dz$ on the parabola $y=x^2$ between $x\in[-1,1]$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

$\int_{\gamma}\operatorname{Re}(z)+\operatorname{Im}(z)\,dz$ on the parabola $y=x^2$ between $x\in[-1,1]$
my try:
$z=x(t)+iy(t)\\x=4(t-0.5)^{2}\\y=2x-1$

whereas gamma is from the range [0,1]

$\int_{0}^{1}x(t)x'(t)\,dt+\int_{0}^{1}y(t)y'(t)\,dt$

Comment: When you wrote that $x=[-1,1]$, did you mean that $x\in[-1,1]$? And what do you mean when you write that $\gamma$ “is from the range $[0,1]$”?

Comment: meaning the path is defined from 0 to 1, and yes, x belongs to [-1,1]

Comment: @MarkViola I'm so sorry, it took so long. Happy holiday to you and all your family. I appreciate your answer.

Comment: @thecorrectanswer No worry.  You've probably had lots of other things to do.  I understand.  And you're certainly welcome.  It was my pleasure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is incorrect to write $\int_\gamma (x+y)\,dz=\int_0^1 x(t)x'(t)\,dt +\int_0^1 x(t)x'(t)\,dt$.

Rather, we have $x(t)=t$, $y(t)=t^2$, and $dz=(x'(t)+iy'(t))\,dt$, where $t$ begins at $-1$ and terminates at $1$.  Hence,

$$\begin{align}
\int_\gamma (x+y)\,dz&=\int_{-1}^1(t+t^2)\,(1+i2t)\,dt 
\end{align}$$

And the interested reader can finish the exercise now.

Comment: Attention that I've changed the path I chose. Is it ok?

Comment: and why it's incorrct?

Comment: @thecorrectanswer The path you defined by $y=x^2$ for $x\in [-1,1]$.  If we parameterize with $x=t$, then $y=t^2$.

Comment: you're right but later I changed it to [0,1]

Comment: Then, the integral extends from $0$ to $1$ instead of $-1$ to $1$.